# Reg Expression to Match '<?' Only

Tags: regex, phpstorm

I'm trying to search a app for any use of `<?` rather than `<?php` with PHPStorm with a regular expression.

After checking out https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371417?hl=en#Match-Whole-Word-Only I've tried `(\W|^)<?(\W|$)` but it does not work.

Any idea what I should use.

Comment: Doing this with in a php source can be dangerous. Imagine a php source that contains a string with `<?` inside. As an aside `<?` is not a word (in a regex meaning).

Comment: you should do  `\?` instead of `?` and try this `<\?[\s]` assuming that there is a space after `<?` tag.

Comment: @Kamran thankyou `<\?[\s]` worked nicely.

Comment: @CreedBratton you are welcome. I have posted this as answer as it might help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<\?[\s]` will match assuming that there is a space after `<?`.